# Не определенная функция get_header

Tags: wordpress

Установил wordpress согласно сайту https://ipipe.ru/info/ustanovka-wordpress-na-openserver и затем захотел использовать underscores.me, на котором ввел worldelectronics и нажал кнопку generate (в результате появилось запрос на перезапись файлов wordpress-а). После открытия создаваемого сайта worldelectronics.ru в браузере появилось сообщение об ошибке

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\OSPanel\domains\worldelectronics.ru\index.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\worldelectronics.ru\index.php on line 15
```

Ниже приведен файл index.php

```html
    <?php
    /**
     * The main template file
     *
     * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
     * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
     * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
     * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
     *
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
     *
     * @package WorldElectronics
     */

    get_header();
    ?>

        <main id="primary" class="site-main">

            <?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :

                if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) :
                    ?>
                    <header>
                        <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                    </header>
                    <?php
                endif;

                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the Post-Type-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Type name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

                endwhile;

                the_posts_navigation();

            else :

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

            endif;
            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->

    <?php
    get_sidebar();
    get_footer();
```

Подскажите как добиться вывода главной страницы сайта темы worldelectronics, взятой с сайта underscores.me.

Comment: а куда вы тему положили?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

underscores.me генерирует просто тему wordpress. Это не вордпресс

Нужно :

1. Установить Wordpress
2. Скопировать тему в wp-content/themes/
3. Активировать ее